# Thread application in Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I'm learning managing with threads in Qt, so please apologize me if I'm making trivial mistakes. Let's back to the topic.

**Short description:**

I wrote small application for testing how threads work. I have simple GUI interface with two buttons. Each of them can starts and stops different thread. Threads are based on **Worker** class under [this link](https://wiki.qt.io/QThreads_general_usage). I'm compiling my code with **Qt Creator** under **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64**.

**Main questions:**

1. When I try start thread it works proper. Then I stop it and try to start again. In this case thread doesn't start. Maby I'm closing thread by inproper way?
2. Is this way of managing with threads is proper? Is it done well? I read about that moving QObject to threads is better in Qt than subclass threads. (But it depends, I know).

**My code:**

**worker.h:**

```
#ifndef WORKER_H
#define WORKER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QMutex>

class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Worker(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    void stop();
    void setMessage(const QString &message);

signals:
    void finished();

public slots:
    void process();

private:
    volatile bool stopped;
    QString messageStr;
    QMutex mutex;
};

#endif // WORKER_H
```

**worker.cpp:**

```
#include "worker.h"
#include <QDebug>

Worker::Worker(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
    stopped = false;
}

void Worker::process()
{
    forever
    {
        mutex.lock();
        if(stopped)
        {
            stopped = false;
            mutex.unlock();
            break;
        }
        mutex.unlock();
        qDebug() << messageStr;
    }
    emit finished();
}

void Worker::stop()
{
    mutex.lock();
    stopped = true;
    mutex.unlock();
}

void Worker::setMessage(const QString &message)
{
    messageStr = message;
}
```

**mydialog.h:**

```
#ifndef MYDIALOG_H
#define MYDIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>

class Worker;

class MyDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyDialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

private slots:
    void startStopThreadA();
    void startStopThreadB();
    void showWorkingGUI();

private:
    Worker *workerA;
    Worker *workerB;
    QThread *threadA;
    QThread *threadB;
    QPushButton *threadAButton;
    QPushButton *threadBButton;
    QPushButton *quitButton;

};

#endif // MYDIALOG_H
```

**mydilog.cpp:**

```
#include "mydialog.h"
#include "worker.h"

#include <QCloseEvent>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTimer>

MyDialog::MyDialog(QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
{
    //Here bla bla for gui
    threadAButton = new QPushButton(tr("Start A"));
    threadBButton = new QPushButton(tr("Start B"));
    quitButton = new QPushButton(tr("Quit"));

    connect(threadAButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(startStopThreadA()));
    connect(threadBButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(startStopThreadB()));

    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(threadAButton);
    layout->addWidget(threadBButton);
    layout->addWidget(quitButton);

    setLayout(layout);

    //Create worker's instances
    workerA = new Worker;
    workerB = new Worker;

    workerA->setMessage("Thread 1");
    workerB->setMessage("Thread 2");

    //Create threads instances
    threadA = new QThread;
    threadB = new QThread;

    //Move worker to thread
    workerA->moveToThread(threadA);
    workerB->moveToThread(threadB);

    connect(threadA, SIGNAL(started()), workerA, SLOT(process()));
    connect(workerA, SIGNAL(finished()), threadA, SLOT(quit()));
    connect(workerA, SIGNAL(finished()), workerA, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(threadA, SIGNAL(finished()), threadA, SLOT(deleteLater()));

    connect(threadB, SIGNAL(started()), workerB, SLOT(process()));
    connect(workerB, SIGNAL(finished()), threadB, SLOT(quit()));
    connect(workerB, SIGNAL(finished()), workerB, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(threadB, SIGNAL(finished()), threadB, SLOT(deleteLater()));

    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(showWorkingGUI()));
    timer->start(1000);

}

void MyDialog::startStopThreadA()
{
    if(threadA->isRunning())
    {
        workerA->stop();
        threadAButton->setText(tr("Start A"));
    }
    else
    {
        threadA->start();
        threadAButton->setText(tr("Stop A"));
    }
}

void MyDialog::startStopThreadB()
{
    if(threadB->isRunning())
    {
        workerB->stop();
        threadBButton->setText(tr("Start B"));
    }
    else
    {
        threadB->start();
        threadBButton->setText(tr("Stop B"));
    }
}

void MyDialog::showWorkingGUI()
{
    qDebug() << "GUI Thread works!";
}
```

**And main.cpp:**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "mydialog.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MyDialog dialog;
    dialog.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**Please for some help. Don't laugh at me if I made some mistakes. I'm really new in threads :)**

**EDIT:** 
I forgot to attach image:
[image]

Comment: ***When I try start thread it works proper. Then I stop it and try to start again. In this case thread doesn't start. Maby I'm closing thread by inproper way?*** I think you can only start a thread 1 time.

Comment: You may want to force this `connect(threadA, SIGNAL(started()), workerA, SLOT(process()));` to use a `Qt::QueuedConnection`

Comment: "volatile bool stopped;" - note: `volatile` does *not* mean thread safe. You probably want `atomic<bool>` there.

Comment: The thread gets destructed after it stops. So you are calling `if(threadA->isRunning())` after `threadA` was freed.

Comment: `MyDialog::startStopThreadA()` should just create a new thread if needed using the advice from @JesperJuhl about the atomic to determine if it is stopped or not.

Comment: Thanks for answers. I made some changes, but I see app freezes now. Maby better idea will be create forever loop like I did, ant then execute code only if stopped == 0, if not just leave this part of code and still execute forever loop.

Comment: @drescherjm, 'MyDialog::startStopThreadA()' should also create new worker and move it into newly created thread? What happens with worker and thread objects after finish thread ?

Comment: I think you can move the original worker to the new thread.

Comment: I fugured out how to solve my issues with yours help. Now everything works like it should. Thanks again guys.

Answer (score 0):

Creating new object inside button method instead `MyDialog` ctor solved my problem. For example:

```
void MainWindow::startStopThreadA()
{
    //First method - start/stop thread
    if(threadA && threadA->isRunning())
    {
        workerA->stop();
        threadA = nullptr;
        ui->threadAButton->setText("Start A");
    }
    else
    {
        threadA = new QThread;
        workerA = new WorkerObject;
        workerA->setMessage("Thread A running");
        workerA->moveToThread(threadA);

        connect(threadA, SIGNAL(started()), workerA, SLOT(process()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
        connect(workerA, SIGNAL(finished()), threadA, SLOT(quit()));
        connect(workerA, SIGNAL(finished()), workerA, SLOT(deleteLater()));
        connect(threadA, SIGNAL(finished()), threadA, SLOT(deleteLater()));

        threadA->start();
        ui->threadAButton->setText("Stop A");
    }
}
```