# Signal/slot multithreading Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals-slots

I know that this is next question about connect signal/slot mechanism between threads. I wrote working [Worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44832625/thread-application-in-qt) application.

**Main problem**

I have worker class that has been moved to another thread. Second part of application is GUI interface with button. When I click button thread starts:

```
void MainWindow::startStopThreadA()
{
    ...
    else
    {
        threadA = new QThread;
        workerA = new WorkerObject;
        workerA->setMessage("Thread A running");
        workerA->moveToThread(threadA);

        connect(threadA, SIGNAL(started()), workerA, SLOT(process()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
        connect(workerA, SIGNAL(finished()), threadA, SLOT(quit()));
        connect(workerA, SIGNAL(finished()), workerA, SLOT(deleteLater()));
        connect(threadA, SIGNAL(finished()), threadA, SLOT(deleteLater()));
        //Connect signal from thread with slot from MainWindow
        connect(workerA, SIGNAL(printMessage(QString)), this, SLOT(printMessage(QString)), Qt::QueuedConnection);

        threadA->start();
        ui->threadAButton->setText("Stop A");
    }
}
```

When thread starts then emits signal:

```
void WorkerObject::process(void)
{
    //Infinity thread loop
    forever
    {
        //Exit loop part
        mutex.lock();
        if(m_stop)
        {
            m_stop = false;
            mutex.unlock();
            break;
        }
        mutex.unlock();

        //Hold/unhold loop part
        mutex.lock();
        if(!m_hold)
        {
            mutex.unlock();
            //Here signal is emited
            emit printMessage(messageStr);          //That not works
            //qDebug() << "Thread A test message."; //That works properly
        }
        mutex.unlock();
    }
    emit finished();
}
```

In main GUI thread I have timer for show that GUI thread works. So `qDebug()` works fine and prints messages from my thread. Also timer from GUI thread works fine and prints message inside `textEdit` GUI field.

Now when `printMessage` signal is emited, GUI thread executes slot method:

```
void MainWindow::printMessage(QString str)
{
    ui->textEdit->append(str);
}
```

**And this is most important part of my problem:**

When signal `printMessage` from `workerA` object is connected with GUI slot `printMessage` with `Qt::QueuedConnection` **my application hangs up**. There is no possible to click something button or even exit app.

When signal/slot are connected with `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection` everything works fine. Messages are emitted and received between threads and also GUI timer works fine.

So my question is why connection `Qt::QueuedConnection` causes that app freezes ?

Comment: That is strange, normally it should work. Can you break/pause your program using a debugger and check what the main/GUI thread is doing? You can try to perform a `QThread::sleep` inside your forever loop (f.e. 1 second) to check if it solves your problem.

Comment: @m7913d, Yes, that really helped me. I used `QThread::msleep(2)` for example and that really working now. Maby signal was emitted too frequently.
@G.M., is definied in `worker` as `QString messageStr` and value is assigned in worker's ctor. In main GUI is only read from emitted signal.

Comment: Does this solves your problem? If so, you may consider writing an answer yourself. If not, please clarify further.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this problem with @m7913d help.

> You can try to perform a QThread::sleep inside your forever loop (f.e.
>   1 second) to check if it solves your problem.

So worker's thread emitted signal too frequently. Adding `QThread::msleep(5)` after emitted signal really helped. There ` also need to be included.